# Python operation on either an array or dataframe that requires updating every row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to learn python/pandas and have no idea how to approach this

Given:

```
df =

              P1      P2      P3       P4      P5
Date                                                  
2017-01-20   808.23  135.60  107.64  53.20  57.66
2017-01-27   835.77  138.30  109.29  53.18  56.13
2017-02-03   810.07  137.92  110.28  52.34  55.05
2017-02-10   827.48  139.87  109.27  56.23  56.22
2017-02-17   845.06  142.91  110.02  56.74  57.35
2017-02-24   845.23  145.89  110.29  57.83  57.48
2017-03-03   849.85  147.77  111.20  56.68  57.09
2017-03-10   852.20  146.88  110.95  56.45  54.54
2017-03-17   852.31  149.57  111.67  57.79  55.79
2017-03-24   845.60  147.77  112.17  56.37  56.81
```

Lets say I had an updating variable initially set at x = 1000. After an operation is done on the first row where I used x as a part of an equation, let's say I got final result of first row = 1005. Then I want x = 1005, and do the said equation with x on the second row where the final result of the second row = 1010. Then I would want to update x = 1010 and do the same thing throughout the dataframe. I imagine it would have to do something with a for loop, and I was thinking it might be easier/better to do this after converting said dataframe into a numpy array but I was hoping to get some tips on iterating over the dataset and updating a variable based on the result of the row before it.

Any tips would be great! Thank you so much.

Comment: First tip is to read [mcve] and edit (or write a new question) accordingly.  It makes your question more useful to the community and easier to answer.

Comment: Are you modifying each row, or just using the row to calculate the corresponding `x`value?  Are you accumulating these `x` values, or just using the last to set the next?

Comment: @piRSquared I will be making a better question following the guidelines. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @hpaulj I will be creating a new question and I hope you will be able to help me there!

Answer (score 0):

Latest pandas version includes a built-in function for iterating over rows.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # do some logic here and modify the value of x as per your needs
    # Or, if you want it faster use itertuples()
```

Comment: This blogger doesn't like `iterrows`, claiming it is too slow: https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc